# Segmentation fault in libusb 1.0 program when run as user, not as sudo

Tags: c++, linux, cimg, libusb-1.0

I'm writing a camera capture program that uses [libusb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libusb) 1.0 and cImg. It connects to my [Atik 314L](http://www.atik-cameras.com/products/info/atik-314-l-plus) astronomy camera and captures images to display on screen. It compiles fine when compiled as regular or superuser and runs well when executed as a root user, but generates a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) when run any other way.

I'm using [Code::Blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code%3a%3aBlocks), and the call stack shows that the segmentation fault happens when calling the `usb_control_msg()` function:

```
#0 (usb_control_msg(dev=0x0, requesttype=64, request=160, value=58880, index=0 bytes=0x7fffffffe5df "\001 \346\377\377\377\177", size=1, timeout=500) (linux.c:152)
```

I'm rather new to programming in a Linux environment, and I'm not sure what to do to get this to run for normal users. Here are the steps I've tried so far:

1. Add my user to all user groups to see if it's a group permissions issue (heck-- I even tried adding myself to "root", but it didn't do anything)
2. Add a rule to `/etc/udev/rules.d` that went a little something like this: PROGRAM="/home/[username]/git/camera/prog", MODE="0660", GROUP="camera"
3. Try to change permissions of the program itself to 777. That was a last ditch effort though-- I didn't really expect it to work.

I'm learning how to debug as I go, so if you need logs or anything to see what's wrong, just let me know.

Comment: Adding Myself to "root"?

Comment: Did you do any `libusb_open();` anywhere in code? If you do so(for debug purpose), it should give you `LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS`. Later, you can Add your user to the 'root' group, that should give you access to all the USB devices and uinput. This is how you can debug if it an Access related issue.

Comment: After adding my user to root, it still segfaults. Any advice as to where to go next?

Comment: Now you should show some code, what you have done. Why would someone want to help you by writing an entire code for you? Instead, let us look what you have done, may be we can figure out something.

Comment: I tried that and it turns out it's not access related.  
The line that is causing the segmentation fault is in `/libusb-0.1.12/linux.c`:  
`ret = ioctl(dev->fd, IOCTL_USB_CONTROL, &ctrl);` is causing it. Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear:

The line that is causing the segmentation fault is in `/libusb-0.1.12/linux.c`:  
`ret = ioctl(dev->fd, IOCTL_USB_CONTROL, &ctrl);` is causing it but I'm not sure how to debug it. What I see is the ioctl function being passed a dereferenced member variable, a defined thing and a variable that's been passed by reference. I looked at the `ioctl.h` file to see how the function works, but it didn't tell me much, and when I tried to find the implementation of ioctl Code::Blocks told me it wasn't found, but I think that's because the .c file isn't included in my project.

Comment: I hope you have included `<sys/ioctl.h>`

Answer (score 1):

You possibly need to set/get the flags of the device using a function like `fnctl()`, and according to your requirement you can set the file access mode (`O_RDONLY / O_WRONLY / O_RDWR`) and file creation flags (`O_CREAT / O_EXCL / O_NOCTTY / O_TRUNC`). However, on Linux this command can change only the `O_APPEND, O_ASYNC, O_DIRECT, O_NOATIME` and `O_NONBLOCK` flags.